# sql query to merge data of two table and display output

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is my two table .

**I need to join both table data And Fetch result accordingly...**

**FOR EX** -

In **scheme Master table** there are 8 rows with different receipt no.

In **receipt entry table** there are only 2 receipt created ...

So i need to display only those balance receipt from scheme master table Which Book and receipt is not present In receipt entry table.

**Table name - scheme_master**

```
book_no2    receipt_no   createddate
401           10          15-03-2015
401           11          15-03-2015
401           12          15-03-2015
401           13          15-03-2015
403           25          15-03-2015
403           26          15-03-2015
403           27          15-03-2015
403           28          15-03-2015
405           35          15-03-2015
405           36          15-03-2015
405           37          15-03-2015
405           38          15-03-2015
```

**Table name -  Receipt_entry**

```
book_no  receipt_no   
401         10           
403         26
```

**I need to get only those receipt which are not present in receipt entry table.**

**Expected output**

```
Book No     Balance Receipt      createddate  

401           11          15-03-2015
401           12          15-03-2015
401           13          15-03-2015

403           25          15-03-2015   
403           27          15-03-2015
403           28          15-03-2015
```

SQL:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT SM.receipt_no AS Receipt,SM.book_no2 AS book,SM.created AS printedDate,SM.city AS cityname FROM scheme_master SM
     LEFT JOIN receipt_entry RE ON RE.receipt_no = SM.receipt_no WHERE
      SM.book_no2 BETWEEN :book_no AND :book2 AND RE.receipt_no IS NULL
```

Comment: Your query seems fine. What is the unexpected output?

Comment: actuall this gets all data from scheme master table..but i need only gets rows of those book which is present in receipt entry table... for ex in my scheme master table there are 3 books no 401,403,405..and in receipt entry table only 401 and 403 are prset ....so i need data of only 401 and 403 book from scheme master except those receipt which are present in receipt entry table...

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't need the `distinct`, if you join correctly on both `book_no` and `receipt_no`.  Second, the condition in the `where` clause is turning the `left join` into an `inner join`, because `NULL` values fail the comparison.  This condition should be on the first table, not the second.

So, try this:

```
SELECT SM.book_no2 AS book, SM.created AS printedDate,
       SM.receipt_no AS Receipt, RE.bookingdate AS bookingdate, RE.surveyor_name FROM scheme_master SM LEFT JOIN
     receipt_entry RE
     ON RE.book_no = SM.book_no2 AND RE.receipt_no = SM.receipt_no
WHERE SM.book_no = 401;
```

Comment: plz sorry actually i post the wrong question on my post now i update my post and query also plz help to achieve this....

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SM.book_no2 AS book,SM.created AS printedDate,SM.receipt_no AS Receipt,RE.bookingdate AS bookingdate,RE.surveyor_name 
FROM scheme_master SM
INNER JOIN Receipt_entry RE
ON RE.book_no = SM.book_no2 AND RE.receipt_no = SM.receipt_no
WHERE RE.book_no = 401;
```

Answer (score 0):

this would be your original query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SM.book_no2 AS book,SM.created AS printedDate,SM.receipt_no AS Receipt,RE.bookingdate AS bookingdate,RE.surveyor_name 
FROM scheme_master SM
LEFT JOIN receipt_entry RE ON RE.book_no = SM.book_no2
```

you can modify it like this one to suite your needs:

```
SELECT SM.book_no2 AS book, SM.created AS printedDate,SM.receipt_no AS Receipt, RE.bookingdate AS bookingdate, RE.surveyor_name 
FROM scheme_master SM 
LEFT JOIN receipt_entry RE
ON RE.book_no = SM.book_no2 
AND RE.receipt_no = SM.receipt_no;
```

we left joined the two statements so that the query will output in the `same row` the values with the same `book_number` and `receipt_number` then displays the `booking date` and `surveyor name` with or without data.

edit:

Please check the following

```
SELECT x.book,x.printedDate,x.Receipt,x.bookingdate,x.surveyor_name
FROM
(
select SM.book_no2 AS book, SM.created AS printedDate,SM.receipt_no AS Receipt, RE.bookingdate AS bookingdate, RE.surveyor_name,if(RE.book_no is null,0,RE.book_no) book_no,if(RE.receipt_no is null,0,RE.receipt_no) receipt_no
FROM scheme_master SM 
LEFT JOIN receipt_entry RE
ON RE.book_no = SM.book_no2 
AND RE.receipt_no = SM.receipt_no
union
select if(SM.book_no2 is null,0,SM.book_no2) AS book, SM.created AS printedDate,if(SM.receipt_no is null,0,SM.receipt_no) AS Receipt, RE.bookingdate AS bookingdate, RE.surveyor_name,RE.book_no,RE.receipt_no
FROM scheme_master SM 
RIGHT JOIN receipt_entry RE
ON RE.book_no = SM.book_no2 
AND RE.receipt_no = SM.receipt_no
) x
WHERE x.book != x.book_no
AND x.Receipt != x.receipt_no
```

Comment: plz sorry actually i post the wrong question on my post now i update my post and query also plz help to achieve this....

Comment: @payaldubey If have updated my answer, please notify me if it contains any errors.

Comment: your query fetch all data from scheme_master table but i need only those book which exist in receipt_entry table NOT ALL book  for ex in my scheme master table there are 3 books no 401,403,405..and in receipt entry table only 401 and 403 are prset ....so i need data of only 401 and 403 book from scheme master except those receipt which are present in receipt entry table...

Comment: Ok sorry for that, I have updated my answer, please check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query:

```
select s.book_no2 as "Book No", s.receipt_no as "Balance Receipt", s.createddate
  from scheme s join receipt r on (s.book_no2 = r.book_no) 
  where s.receipt_no not in (select receipt_no from receipt);
```

A demo result can be seen here: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5db6a/2)